# Будильник Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Делаю что-то вроде будильника, как можно указать сразу два будильника? Просто если использовать этот же код и изменять время, то будильник просто переставиться на последнее выставленное время. Разве что создать кучу классов AlarmReceiver... Есть какие-то варианты решения?

```
                   isay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,11);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 31);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;
            final Intent my_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VoiceRecognitionActivity.this, 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(VoiceRecognitionActivity.this, "Будильник включен",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
        }
    });




public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String not;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("extra");
    Intent service_intent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
    service_intent.putExtra("extra", name);
    context.startService(service_intent);

}
```

Comment: Нужно сделать `PendingIntent` "разными". Например: менять requestCode или добавлять в `Intent` разные action.

Comment: Не работает, Вот так сделал
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VoiceRecognitionActivity.this, 1, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(VoiceRecognitionActivity.this, 2, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);